# CSS - Class not registering when combined with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird one that I can't seem to be able to figure out. I am new to CSS and decided to use bootstrap to assist with styles etc.

the problem I have is when I try to assign two classes to a div element, 1 being the bootstrap column and another from my own stylesheet.

the code from my stylesheet seems to be ignored in some cases. now i have taken that one bit of code and css out and put it into the jsfiddle but it works fine. its only when combined with the rest of the html does it seem to have issues. also note that if i use inline styles it works...

I copied the entire code to js fiddle now so that you guys can replicate the issue. the section I am having issues with is the 4 images that are side by side

```
class="services-boxes"
```

anyway any assistance will be appreciated, as well as general feedback as I am new to this all! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/d9bv0grx/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] **in the question itself**, not on a third-party site.

Comment: what particular style is being ignored?

Comment: "*I am new to CSS and decided to use bootstrap*" - this was **the worst decision you could have made**. I can only recommend to **stop using Bootstrap or any other on-top-of-css-technology before you have a very thorough understanding and knowledge of CSS** as it wil a) prevent you from learning the important stuff and b) add alot of complexity to your learning which you will be unable to resolve.

Comment: If a style is being ignored, is it that you're loading your custom stylesheet BEFORE bootstrap? CSS is cascading, meaning the last part is the most relevant.

Comment: Looking at you example tells me you have no clue about CSS yet. Hands off Bootstrap for at least half a year, assuming you work with CSS on a daily basis until then!

Comment: Here's your page with some corrections, I couldn't go any further, it needs more work: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/d9bv0grx/6/

Comment: Ah I uploaded this in a hurry to jsfiddle and forgot to change the syntax back from inline to style sheet. Looks worse than it actually is haha - I copied the inline style to the style of jsfiddle hence the random "" and = signs

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way cascading style sheets work it (styles are be applied in order AND by *specificity*). It is most likely that styles you are expecting to see are being overridden by specificity.

Give [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) guide a read.

An example is that for `<div id="selector">`

```
#selector {background-color:red;}
div {background-color:green;}
```

You can expect to see a div with a red background, even though the green background is set afterwards, the id selector has greater specificity.

Then try and alter the specificity of your selectors in your css so that they will take precedence over in bootstrap.

Also just going to add, you have casing issues - you declare the class with lowercase in css, capitalised in your html.

You also have syntax issues in your css. Your css should look like:

```
.services-boxes {
padding:0;
max-height:500px;
width:100%;
}
```

Sort all this and you should be golden! [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9bv0grx/5/)

Comment: Hairmot, did you take  a look at his fiddle?  Check that out. http://www.screencast.com/t/6oM5GfvrLW You are right. He needs CSS instructions. Upvote!

Comment: Which is exactly why you *don't use #id selectors in CSS*.

Comment: **Zero-lengths should omit the unit.** Also it is recommended to write units and the like in **lowercase letters** only. Your example would also work using a CSS `class` instead of an `id`.

Comment: Ah I uploaded this in a hurry to jsfiddle and forgot to change the syntax back from inline to style sheet. Looks worse than it actually is haha

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a combination of syntax errors. Your style should be declared like this:

```
.services-boxes {
padding:0px;
max-height: 500PX;
width:100%;
}
```

Note that the class is all lowercase (which should match style where declared which is currently Services-Boxes), a colon separating property and value (you has used = in some instances) and one set of curly braces per declaration (the above class .logo-image has 2 closing braces). Just a bit of formatting should see your code recognised

Comment: **Zero-lengths should omit the unit.** Also it is recommended to write units and the like in **lowercase letters** only.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have total control over your HTML, you can use the !important property in css to give a priority to your styles.

```
.services-boxes {
color: red !important;
}
```

However keep in mind that you have to avoid the !important property as much as possible and do not use it unless you can't do it any other way.

Comment: Which is why I'd never recommend a total beginner to use `!important` at all.